# Alternative sites to Google Docs

Tags: creative-writing, websites, google-docs

I'm looking for websites that let me write and store my stories online, so I can keep developing them no matter where I go. (Because of my devices specs, sadly Dropbox — and similar options that need you to install software — can't really work.)

However, I need something either minimalistic or specifically focused on writing fiction literature.

Comment: What's wrong with Google Docs? There are similar webapps out there, but if Google Docs isn't "minimalistic" enough for you then I don't know if they would be suitable either. The more details the better. (Device specs? Free or paid options? Etc.)

Comment: There are literally hundreds of options for this.  I use half a dozen different ones just to keep different projects separated.  You may get a better answer on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/